# Big-O Estimate Problem ("Tightest Big-O Estimate")

Tags: discrete-mathematics, estimation

For $f(n) = (2^n +n^n)(n^3+n\text{log}(n^n))$, what is the tightest big-O estimate?

My attempt is the following:

We can break this into two product statements: $(2^n +n^n) \text{ and }(n^3+n\text{log}(n^n))$

Focusing on the left most: $(2^n + n^n) \le (n^n + n^n) \text{ then } O(n^n)$

Now the right most: $n^3+n\text{log}(n^n) \rightarrow n^3 + n^2\text{log}(n) \le n^3 + n^3 \text{ then } O(n^3)$

Then all together we have: $O(n^{n+3})$

Is this the correct way to calculate this? Super new to this, and I have to admit, getting to the $O$ estimation is... strange, and I don't feel like my justification is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, although you should say something about how you know this is tight.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't know what it means for this to me a tight estimate.

Comment: I would interpret it as meaning that $f(n)$ is also $\Omega(n^{n+3})$; that is, it's not only bounded from above by a constant times $n^{n+3}$, it's also bounded from below by a constant times $n^{n+3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic strategy is correct, but the way it's normally explain would be slightly different. Since $n\log(n^n)=n^2\log n\in o(n^3)$, $n^3+n\ln(n^n)\in O(n^3)$ (or which is stronger, $n^3+n\ln(n^n)\sim n^3$). Similarly, $2^n\in o(n^n)$ implies $2^n+n^n\sim n^n$. So $f\sim n^{n+3}$. This stronger than $f\in O(n^{n+3})$; it's also sufficient to prove no tighter big-$O$ characterization is possible.